# Advertising on website opens Google Play Store. How can I prevent that?

Tags: browser, hyperlinks

A website I recently visited on my Android device (http://forums.mtgsalvation.com) has code on the page (likely in the advertising banner at the top) that forces my Android's Google Play Store application to open up to Candy Crush. The link it's using:

```
market://details?id=com.king.candycrushsaga&referrer=ACID155-1378233900389-90097883
```

This is an unwanted action. Other than no longer visiting this site on my Android devices, is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I had two thoughts on the matter. Changing the agent to something that would not indicate that my device was running Android, or to disable the Play Store by deleting the vend app from a rooted device.

I'd like to avoid such nuclear options if possible.

Comment: That's what the `market:` protocol is supposed to do, although if they're automatically opening that link I'd bet it's violating Google's ToS. (And that looks like an affiliate ID to boot. Dirty pool all around.) I think your best bet is to use a browser that lets you change the user-agent.

Comment: Or just don't use such a sleazy site.

Comment: To start with, I write a fiercely worded complaint to the website admin, and then make sure I tell everyone to stop visiting such spammy websites.

Comment: If it's actually in violation of Google's TOS, then https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1085703?hl=en ... report it to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Better way - block it on that site.

Try installing [Adblock Plus for Android](https://adblockplus.org/en/android-install). According to Adblock Plus official website it
"Blocks banners, pop-ups and video ads - even on Facebook and YouTube".

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted, you could use [`AdAway`](http://sufficientlysecure.org/index.php/adaway/) to block advertisment of almost any kind on your device.

The app uses android's hosts-file to block/redirect queries to online adresses hosting advertisments.

In other words, every time an app tries to load advertisment from a specific online source, it's very likely that `AdAway` successfully redirects or blocks that attemp. In that case, the advertisment simply won't appear at all, resulting in an ad-free experience while using your phone.

Sadly, though, Google decided to take down ad-blocking apps like `AdAway` for violating Android's Developer Distribution Agreement.

If you wish to use `AdAway` anyway, you'll have to resort to third-party-sources. Please note that this bears significant security risks. Proceed at your own responsibility!

1. Make sure the installation of apps from `unknown sources` is allowed in `system settings` under `security`.
2. Download and install [`F-Droid`](https://f-droid.org/)
3. Open `F-Droid`, search for and install `AdAway`.
4. Open `AdAway` and grant root-access when asked.
5. Click on `Download files and apply blocking`.

[image]

That's it, you're all set. You can refine some of the app's configuration under `settings`, e.g. automate the update of hosts file process.